# Access denied Running a ASP.Net site from VS2013 on local IIS

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2013

Access to the path 'C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\xxx\xxx\Areas\HostSettings\Views\Home\Index.cshtml' is denied.

I get the following error when I run a my ASP.NET MVC site on local IIS I am not sure why? I am the admin on the machine and am running VS as an administrator

Answer (score 0):

If it is not `IIS Express` which is launched with Visual Studio Debugger, then it does not matter whether you are running VS as administrator or not. Because `IIS` does not run in current user context. `IIS` has its own user -

http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/planning-for-security/understanding-built-in-user-and-group-accounts-in-iis

You should give access to that user (`IIS_IUSRS/IUSR/IUSR_MachineName` depending on your `IIS` version) to that path.